# AngularJS | Add / Remove Class Using Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm new to AngularJS and needing help on how to toggle classes on form elements if the input is valid or invalid.

I have noted that most validation is done within the DOM - see here: https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation

However, I'm wanting to avoid using the dom to handle validation. I want to use a custom directive to handle if a input is valid or invalid based upon validation rules.

Here is my HTML / Angular markup so far:

```
<fieldset ng-class="{error: loginForm.username.$invalid}">  
            <div class="form-input-error" ng-show="loginForm.$error">
                Username is too short.
            </div>
            <div class="vfnz-fieldWrapper">
                <input 
                    type="text" 
                    id="username" 
                    ng-model="username"
                    class="vfnz-input--text" 
                    placeholder="Username" 
                    ng-minlength="3" 
                    ng-maxlength="8" />
                <label for="name" class="vfnz-input-label">
                    Username
                </label>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
```

Here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/beuL679o/3/) of my code so far

Basically when a input is invalid - add class to the fieldset. If the input is valid add class to fieldset.

Answer (score 0):

from angular 1.3.x they came up with ng-messages ,i think you should try this. The advantages of using it is  it will show the appropiate error if your input contains multiple error's.Add your class to the validation div

the below example checks for required and number .

```
                      <form name='cliForm'>
                        <input  ng-model="vm.formData.newCreditLimit" type="text" name="changeCreditLimit" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{1,15}$/" required />
                        <div class="highlight" ng-messages="cliForm.changeCreditLimit.$error" ng-if="cliForm.$submitted">
                            <div ng-message="required">* This field is required!</div>
                            <div ng-message="pattern">* Not a valid number!</div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

before using this include the ng-messages script since its in different module and inject the ng-messages to your angular module

Answer (score 0):

I'm also looking for a solution to this issue, but the (lazy) answer I'm opting for right now is just to let some directives determine whether the element is valid or invalid, and just let angular handle the css classes. What I'm doing is to just add the ff to my css file:

```
.ng-invalid {
    border-color: #e51c23;
    color: #e51c23 !important;
 }

.ng-error {
    border-color: #e51c23;
    color: #e51c23 !important;
}

.ng-valid {
    border-color: #4CAF50;
    color: #4CAF50 !important;
}
```